# Incorrect GeoCoordinate at Random

Tags: mobile, silverlight, bing-maps, windows-phone

Sometimes when the device is pulling coordinates with the GeoPositionAccuracy set to High and the MovementThreshold set to 0, the GeoCoordinate that is captured is further away and not inline with the other coordinates. How can I prevent that or remove that GeoCoordinate from my collection of GeoCoordinates? You'll notice that in the imge below right above the second light grey 'e' and to the right on the route 11 symbol, you'll see a little jog out. The same thing under the first little grey 'e'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the MovementThreshold to a higher value:

> The minimum distance that must be travelled between successive PositionChanged events.

See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.movementthreshold%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Even if I set the MovementThreshold to 20, it still picks up the last known GPS location at somepoint in the PositionChanged event. That would/should fix the other jog outs, but since this is a navigation-like app, I have it set to 0 to get better results (or so I choose). The only thing I can think of is invalidating coordinates based on speed and distance that was traveled. If it's not close, I shouldn't add that coordinate. Thoughts?

Comment: See the following for similar gripes: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11288/geocordinatewatcher-issue-in-wp7