# How to get first, most current coordinate in GeoCoordinateWatcher?

Tags: geocoding, silverlight, windows-phone

It seems like when I have an app that uses a GeoCoordinateWatcher and I attempt to get the first coordinate, it always pulls the last coordinate that the GPS used first when raising the PositionChanged event. It's not always the first PositionChanged event, but the last time an app used a GeoCoordinateWatcher.

Any idea why this would be the case? I understand that it also tracks the GPS entry when the device just sits and looks like its not (due to the sensitivity).

Comment: What settings are you using on the DesiredAccuracy and MovementThreshold properties? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher_members%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try checking that the [status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.status%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) is ready. Also check if you get an old [timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792375%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) on the GeoPosition that is returned by the changed event.